# is there any way to $_POST data inside a newly created iframe inside of a modal?

Tags: jquery, pdf, post, iframe, simplemodal

i have a form that will generate a pdf file after submiting the input data...i want to make the user be able to preview the pdf so i come up w/ a iframe inside a simplemodal...i want to send $_POST data to an iframe..that is inside of a simple modal created on the fly...i have tried targeting the iframe but it doesn't work...i've searched through the net but nothing works for me...please help!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that from the $_POST you are using PHP.  Files that are uploaded through post are not stored in the POST array, but rather in the $_FILES array.  Refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) MAN page on how to use it.

Be sure to move the file to a directory of choice before you try to retrieve it.

Comment: no i am using the $_POST global varibale...i'm using it to generate pdf contents...and stream it to the user.